# Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was String then Worker fail response

Tags: java, android, android-studio, retrofit

I am using retrofit to fetch web API

My API Call as follows:

```
@POST(ApiConstant.ADD_MEMBER)
Call<MemberResponse> addMember(@Body Map<String, Object> map);
```

Response Call

```
HashMap<String, Object> list = new HashMap<>();
    list.put("code", TinyDB.getInstance().getString(PrefrenceConstent.TRAINER_CODE));
    list.put("first_name", TinyDB.getInstance().getString(PrefrenceConstent.KEY_NAME));
    list.put("email", TinyDB.getInstance().getString(PrefrenceConstent.KEY_USER_EMAIL));
    list.put("contact", TinyDB.getInstance().getString(PrefrenceConstent.KEY_USER_MOBILE));
    list.put("last_name", "Null");

    try {
        Response<MemberResponse> responseAllInvites = ApiBuilder.getApiInterfaceCoachPro().addMember(list).execute();
        if (responseAllInvites.body() != null) {
            Timber.e("Response: %s", responseAllInvites.body().getData());
            MemberInfo invitationsList = responseAllInvites.body().getData();
            String member_code = invitationsList.getMember_code();
            Timber.e("Member Code: %s", member_code);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return Result.failure();
    }
```

POJO

```
public class MemberResponse {
@SerializedName("data")
@Expose
private MemberInfo data;

@SerializedName("Message")
@Expose
private String message;

public MemberInfo getData() {
    return data;
}

public void setData(MemberInfo data) {
    this.data = data;
}

public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}

public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}}
```

Expected JSON Response

```
{
"data": {
    "id": 84,
    "member_code": "testcrm-72807-47474-12"
},
"Message": "Member details were successfully created!"}
```

I am getting below error

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 10 path $.data

Comment: you probably got xml response

Comment: I got response in Json formate

Comment: Try to get your response as String instead of your POJO object and put it into some online json formatter and you will see what you have wrong there. Anyway it's an error with json format so something went wrong there